# Position or row in which a term is found in vector

Tags: r

I would like to indicate the possition or row of elements in vectors

```
df <- data.frame(G1=c("a","b","e","d","c"),
                 G2=c("a","c","b","d","e"))
```

In this case G1 is the reference, so "a" is the first, "b", the second, "e", third and so on. 
What I would like to see in G2 is that "a" is first, but "b" now is third. So I can get this output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(G1=c(1:5), G2=c(1, 3, 5, 4, 2))
row.names(df2) <- c("a","b","e","d","c")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `match`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) match(df$G1, x)), row.names=df$G1)
#   G1 G2
# a  1  1
# b  2  3
# e  3  5
# d  4  4
# c  5  2
```